# How to insert an RSS item in the Wordpress feed?

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

I am developing a Wordpress plugin that needs to dynamically insert a RSS item in the feed.

I have an admin form that the user will submit and save to a custom table. It has a title, link, and content fields. I need these records to be included in the RSS feed.

I have been looking everywhere and cannot find any solution. Is this even possible?

Comment: It sounds like you may want to update an existing feed data, which [the_content_feed() hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content_feed/) may be helpful. If you're looking to create a custom RSS, review the [Customizing_Feeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds) documentation

Comment: looks like I will need to create a custom RSS for this. thanks @wouch